# Creating a page in Drupal that has a dynamic URL without Views or Panels

Tags: url, drupal

With both views and panels (via the page manager), you can create a page that accepts arguments like users/%/points.

However, I don't need any of the other functionality of these modules beyond the creation of that dynamic page URL. I simply want to create a page that will appear when someone is at the url users/%/points. How can I set up a URL like that without using a module like Views or Panels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal has a system to create dynamic pages, this is what happens when you view a node or a user. You got a few options, but it all happens in [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6).

```
function modulename_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['users/%user/points'] = array(
        'page callback' => callback, // the function to call
        'page arguments' => array(1), // The argument to pass, 1 = %user, which will be a user object.
         ...
    );
    $items['users/%/points'] = array(...);
    $items['users/points'] = array(...);
}
```

In the first example, you utilize Drupal's load system. Drupal will call user_load on the argument index at 1, if it finds a user, that will be available instead of the actual argument (the user id). If no user is found 404 will be returned.

In the second example, any argument is allowed, which means that you would get a page if you tried to access `user/my-little-pony/points`.

In the third example is used to show that Drupal allow additional args. So if you want to access `user/points/pony`, you would get the `user/points` page with additional args which could be used, if your callback function allows it.

Remember to set some sort of access control as well. You can define custom functions to determine if the user should have access, you use the drupal menu system and require permissions, like `access content`.

Ready made code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function example_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user/%/points'] = array(
    'title' => 'Page title here',
    'description' => 'Description here, mostly used for admin pages',
    'page callback' => 'example_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1)
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

example_callback($arg) {
  return t('The arg is @arg', array('@arg' => $arg));
}
```

This would need to go into example.module and you would need to create an example.info file. You could change example into whatever module you have created.

Comment: Great. I'm going to need more assistance to get this working though. I assume that I put this code into the modulename.install file, correct? Here's what I've done: 1) renamed modulename_menu with the name of my module (custom_functions_menu)  2) Deleted the '...' inside the second $items array  3) deleted the third and fourth $items arrays since I first just want to get a basic version of this working (i.e. only users/%/points) before going for greater functionality.  4) ran update.php (no idea if this is necessary, but it was worth a shot). In the end, I still get a "page not found" error.

Comment: @maxedison, your code should be put in `.module` file. `.install` is for installation hooks, like creating database table and inserting things in the database. You can take a look at [the handbook](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) to read more about module development. Btw, you need to create a callback function as well, just create a function that returns a text string for startes to see that everything works. Also when changing stuff in hook_menu you need to clear the menu cache.

Comment: still no luck. I've moved the code to the .module file, made the page callback function return a string, and used the "Clear cached data" button on the Performance page (that does clear the menu cache, no?). I'm still getting a page not found error.

Comment: @maxedison: I've posted a code snippet, if you are still having trouble, update your answer with the code you got...

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. The problem was that the name of the callback function in example_menu() didn't have quotes around it. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, it can be done quite easily with hook_menu inside a custom module. Here is example for dynamic page with dynamic title created with variable that the user inserts.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['user/points/%/'] = array(
'page callback' => 'MY_PAGE_CALLBACK_FUNCTION',
'title callback' => 'MY_PAGE_CALLBACK_TITLE_FUNCTION',
'title arguments' => array(3), 
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

```
function MY_PAGE_CALLBACK_TITLE_FUNCTION($arg) {
  return "My dynamic title: " . $arg;
}
```